# How do i install dlib on fedora 30?

Tags: python, anaconda, fedora, dlib

I'm using the face_recognition module for a hobby project. And i download the source code from GitHub and put it in my project folder. It works fine.

How do i properly install dlib on fedora 30?

I tried installing dlib through pip and anaconda, neither worked.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [package repos](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/dlib/overview), you should be able to install dlib from the official repositories by running

```
sudo dnf install python3-dlib
```

Comment: It works, kind of... It installed fine, however when i import it in my program it says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dlib'
`

Comment: @ShyaamRamesh I think you may need to also reinstall `face_recognition`, as it has to build an extension that uses `dlib` during its installation.

Comment: @merv i have not installed face_recognition. I've just downloaded the source and in python, `import face_recognition`

Comment: @ShyaamRamesh Though I still recommend my answer as better practice for Conda envs, if you wanted this one to work I think you need to install `face_recognition`. I.e., activate your env, then `pip install -e path/to/face_recognition`. However, if this is your **base** env, I would strongly discourage this. Using `pip` can put Conda in an unstable state and you definitely don't want that with **base**.

Comment: @ShyaamRamesh Sorry, I missed the fact that you wanted the Python lib, and not the C++ library. The package is called `python3-dlib`. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Quick Install

[It's on Conda Forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/dlib), so you can use

```
conda install -c conda-forge dlib
```

### Recommended Practice

Even better, use a YAML and create a new env for your project. For example, if you want a minimal env just to run `face_recognition` then the following YAML would be sufficient:

#### face_rec.yaml

```
name: face_rec
channels:
 - conda-forge
dependencies:
 - python=3.7
 - click>=6.0
 - dlib>=19.7
 - numpy
 - pillow
 - cmake
 - pip
 - pip:
   -  -e git+ssh://git@github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition.git#egg=face_recognition
```

Then create the environment like:

```
conda env create -n my_env -f face_rec.yaml
```

where `my_env` is whatever you want to name it. You can freely add whatever other packages you anticipate needing into this. Alternatively, if you really do want a full Anaconda Python distribution + face-recognition, then replace the `python=3.7` with just `anaconda`. It will take significantly longer to solve, though.

In the end, this is the best practice for working with with Conda, especially when you install packages from PyPI/GitHub. See "[*Using Pip in a Conda Environment*](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/)" for details.