# unable to correctly complete conda install face_recognition

Tags: python, pip, conda

I have been working on some facial detection code with OpenCV, however recently I needed a fetcher from a module, **face_recognition**. I first tried installing it with `pip install face_recognition` and then with `conda install`...

What I eventually ended up doing is creating a separate virtual environment for Anaconda in PyCharm and I installed all the **face_recognition** dependencies successfully with `conda install`, then did `pip install --no-dependencies face_recognition`.
The terminal reported that it had successfully installed **face_recognition**, however when I try running the code, I still get the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'face_recognition'

I have been doing research and trying so many different things for about three days now; I have no idea what else I could do.

**How can I create a Conda environment with the** face_recognition **package?**

Comment: Please provide `conda info --envs` and see what environments you have. You might install it in different environment.

Comment: do you mean this?...
```(py37) C:\Users\Astroid\AppData\Local\Temp\scratch.py>conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
base                     C:\Users\Astroid\Anaconda3
env_dlib                 C:\Users\Astroid\Anaconda3\envs\env_dlib
py37                  *  C:\Users\Astroid\Anaconda3\envs\py37

```

Comment: Yes, try to use the right environment, and re-do all you did, and let us know.

Comment: how do i find out what the right environment will be ?

Comment: Just try each, and import the library or run the script, they should give the different errors, if you still have the issue, I suggest to find one you're comfortable and delete and reinstall the libraries you need. It is very mechanic.

Comment: Consider trying [this YAML for an environment with `face_recognition`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58221427/570918) that I made for another question.